# How to use execv for commands whose location is not known?

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

Say I want to spawn a process and run `execv` to execute a command like `ls` then this is how i do it:

```
char * const parm[] = { "/usr/bin/ls","-l" , NULL };
if ((pid = vfork()) == -1)
    perror("fork error");
else if (pid == 0)
{
    execv("/usr/bin/ls", parm);
}
```

Now the question is that here I have hard coded where the `ls` command is present (`/usr/bin/ls`). Now suppose I do not know where a particular command is present and want to execute it then how do I go about it? I know in a regular shell the `PATH` variable is looked up to achieve the same, but in case of a C program using `execv` how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`execvp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) instead of `execv(3)`.  `execvp` and `execlp` work exactly like `execv` and `execl` respectively, except they search the `$PATH` environment variable for an executable (see the man page for full details).